# Backbone/underscore js "too much recursion" and "Inspect target crashed" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, recursion

I have written a code for to-do list and its working fine but some times it giving error 
**Backbone/underscore js "too much recursion" and "Inspect target crashed" error** like this is console..

**Html Code :-**

```
  <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
      <div class="view">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= completed ? 'checked' : '' %>>
        <label><%- title %></label>
        <input class="edit" value="<%- title %>">
        <button class="destroy">remove</button>
      </div>
    </script>
```

**Backbone JS code :-**

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var app = {}; // create namespace for our app

    //--------------
    // Models
    //--------------
    app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
      },
      toggle: function(){
        this.save({ completed: !this.get('completed')});
      }
    });

    //--------------
    // Collections
    //--------------
    app.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: app.Todo,
      localStorage: new Store("backbone-todo")
    });

    // instance of the Collection
    app.todoList = new app.TodoList();

    //--------------
    // Views
    //--------------

    // renders individual todo items list (li)
    app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',
      template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
      render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.input = this.$('.edit');
        return this; // enable chained calls
      },
      initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this); // remove: Convenience Backbone's function for removing the view from the DOM.
      },      
      events: {
        'dblclick label' : 'edit',
        'keypress .edit' : 'OnEnter',
        'blur .edit' : 'close',
        'click .toggle': 'toggleCompleted',
        'click .destroy': 'destroy'
      },
      edit: function(){
        this.$el.addClass('editing');
        this.input.focus();
      },
      OnEnter: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
          this.close();
        }
      },
      close: function(){
        var value = this.input.val().trim();
        if(value) {
          this.model.save({title: value});
        }
        this.$el.removeClass('editing');
      },
      updateOnEnter: function(e){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(e);
        // if(e.which == 13){
        //   this.close();
        // }
      },
      toggleCompleted: function(){
        this.model.toggle();
      },
      destroy: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
      }      
    });

    // renders the full list of todo items calling TodoView for each one.
    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#todoapp',
      initialize: function () {
        this.input = this.$('#new-todo');
        app.todoList.on('add', this.addAll, this);
        app.todoList.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        app.todoList.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
      },
      events: {
        'keypress #new-todo': 'createTodoOnEnter'
      },
      createTodoOnEnter: function(e){
        if ( e.which !== 13 || !this.input.val().trim() ) { // ENTER_KEY = 13
          return;
        }
        app.todoList.create(this.newAttributes());
        this.input.val(''); // clean input box
      },
      addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo});
        $('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
      },
      addAll: function(){
        this.$('#todo-list').html(''); // clean the todo list
        app.todoList.each(this.addOne, this);
      },
      newAttributes: function(){
        return {
          title: this.input.val().trim(),
          completed: false
        }
      }
    });

    //--------------
    // Initializers
    //--------------   

    app.appView = new app.AppView(); 

  })(jQuery);
```

When I am achieving and OnEnter while keypress the edit its giving me this error..
I checked when "Too much recursion " error comes.. But not able to figure out..

Please dont mind if my question is not clear....

Thanks !!

Comment: If I understood correctly, the infinite recursion occurs when your `OnEnter` function is called, is that right?

Comment: I would use keyup instead of keypress, but that shouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: @akoskm yes correct ..

Comment: @mguimard yes correct keyup will not work.. both are some how same in this manner..

Comment: Cannot see what's wrong there, could you post your model and template ?

Comment: using the browser developer tools' breakpoints, can you please investigate which line exactly is behind this crash?

Comment: @mguimard I have posted my full code with model, view as well as html code.. for reference check it please..

Comment: @jakee thanks for your suggestion.. I am checking the same..

Comment: @Coder: I cannot reproduce the bug, tested on chrome and firefox. What I would change in AppView.initialize : `app.todoList.on('add', this.addAll, this);` to `app.todoList.on('add', this.addOne, this);` Will prevent to render many times the same view at load.

Comment: @mguimard THANKS dude.. I found the solution.. that was related to some conflicts.. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you should try this.
I have given a condition for on enter but my call was going repeatedly ,
So I declared keypress event and function as follows

```
events:{
"keyup #globalOrgSearchInput":"onEnter"
}

onEnter:function(event){
            var me=this;`enter code here`
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
                me.globalOrgSearch();
            }
        },
```